# Play MIDI From TMemoryStream?

Tags: delphi, stream, midi

Is it possible to play a Midi Sequence through a TMemoryStream without using any 3rd Party Libraries?

I can play WAVE Audio through a TMemoryStream, but how about MIDI Sequences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are built in facilities in Windows and simplest is the [`MCIWnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798215%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) window class.  If you need more precise control then the full smörgåsbord of facilities are summarised [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742875%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Having said that I do suspect that a pre-existing 3rd party Delphi wrapper would make life much easier, but you clearly state you don't want to do that.

Comment: @David you are a very knowledgable and skilled programmer, it seems there is little you dont know! Anyway, I have no issue using 3rd party components as they probably encansuplate and manage all the raw stuff for you, I usually try to avoid using 3rd party though and use standard issue components when possible - although I should maybe change my outlook on that.

Comment: These APIs will be quite awkward to use and I'm sure there are good Delphi wrappers around that present MDI capabilities in a more idiomatic Delphi way. That's what you should be looking for. I don't know any such components though.

Comment: -1 a funny word, indeed (how to explain that... unfunny and unclear joke distracts from actual answer dignities, i'd better spend more time at MSDN instead of figuring out "why did he said that?")

Answer (score 0):

I know David gave you the answer with the MCIWnd, and you can build a player based on that API, but if you reconsider using other components I suggest you http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:JclMIDI.pas, is free.